# I am not getting data from api after refreshing the web page in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, conditional-rendering

I am working on a project, where I am using conditional rendering. I am not sure what the cause but I am not getting data from api after refreshing the page.

- Image of the page on [first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUivt.png)
- Image after a [page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW3t4.png)

This is obviously not the desired behavior, what am I missing here? This is my fetch request code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get(path)
    .then((res) => {
      setRoundData(res.data[1]);
      setStudentData(res.data[2]);
      setFilterData(res.data[2]);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, [path]);
```

Comment: Without seeing the code it will be very difficult to help. I suggest you edit the question and include at least your fetch logic.

Answer (score 1):

Create a async function which runs each time the path changes. You could try something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await axios.get(path);
    setRoundData(res.data[1]);
    setStudentData(res.data[2]);
    setFilterData(res.data[2]);
  }
  
  fetchData();
}, [path]);
```